# Using sed to filter RSS items

Tags: sed, curl, rss, feed-reader

I would like to write a script that:

- Takes some RSS-Feed URL as input
- Downloads the feed
- Deletes all `<item> ...</item>` occurrences where the `title` tag does not mach some regular expression.

The following example should illustrate this. Let's say we have an RSS Feed with these three items:

- Project Foo - Let's get started!
- Something Else Entirely
- Another update on Project Foo

I want to keep only those items that have "Project Foo" in their title.

Example input file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
<rss version="2.0">
<channel>
<title>My glorious newsfeed</title>
<description>...</description>
<link>...</link>
<language>...</language>
<pubDate>...</pubDate>

<item>
<title>Project Foo - Let's get started!</title>
<link>...</link>
<description>...</description>
<pubDate>...</pubDate>
</item>

<item>
<title>Something else entirely</title>
<link>...</link>
<description>...</description>
<pubDate>...</pubDate>
</item>

<item>
<title>Another update on Project Foo</title>
<link>...</link>
<description>...</description>
<pubDate>...</pubDate>
</item>

</channel>
</rss>
```

Example output file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
<rss version="2.0">
<channel>
<title>My glorious newsfeed</title>
<description>...</description>
<link>...</link>
<language>...</language>
<pubDate>...</pubDate>

<item>
<title>Project Foo - Let's get started!</title>
<link>...</link>
<description>...</description>
<pubDate>...</pubDate>
</item>

<item>
<title>Another update on Project Foo</title>
<link>...</link>
<description>...</description>
<pubDate>...</pubDate>
</item>

</channel>
</rss>
```

If possible, I would like to stay away from the likes of `python` and do this with command-line tools. But I am a big newbie using `sed` etc. and need some help :)

Here's what I have so far:

```
cat sample-feed.xml \
  | tr -d '\n' \
  | sed $'s/\<item\>/\\\n\<item\>/g;s/\<\/channel\><\/rss\>/\\\n\<\/channel\><\/rss\>/g' \
  | sed '/^\<item\>/ d'
```

First, I delete all newlines. Then, I add newlines to bring every `<item>...</item>` onto its own line. The final command so far deletes all lines that start with `<item>`. For

The result is a valid rss-feed without any items:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?><rss version="2.0"><channel><title>My glorious newsfeed</title><description>...</description><link>...</link><language>...</language><pubDate>...</pubDate>    
</channel></rss>
```

For making this work with URL's instead of local files I would just replace the `cat sample-feed.xml` with `curl -s <some url>`.

What is still missing though is a modification to the command `sed '/^\<item\>/ d'` that only deletes lines that start with `<item>` but do not contain "Project Foo".

So, if you could help me figure out what the last line should say I would be very happy. On the other hand, I am sure there is a more elegant way to do this. From what I've seen `sed` is quite powerful and it should be possible to do this in one `sed` command.

Looking forward to your answers :-)

Comment: Have a look at **xmlstarlet**; it's built to manipulate xml files: http://xmlstar.sourceforge.net/

Comment: [Don't Parse XML/HTML With Regex.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/3776858) I suggest to use an XML/HTML parser (xmlstarlet, xmllint ...).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested in the comments I tried using `xmlstarlet` to solve this and it works well. Here's my script

```
xml ed -d '//item[not(contains(title,"Project Foo"))]' < sample_rss.xml
```

Let's assume the feed content is in the file `sample_rss.xml`.
That content gets fed into `xml ed -d`, which deletes any note matching the given XPath Expression.
The XPath expression looks for any `<item>`  that does not have a node `<title>` which contains the text `"Project Foo"`.

This seems to work well and I am also very happy with the execution time:

```
real    0m0.003s
user    0m0.001s
sys     0m0.002s
```

**Beware of namespaces**

If you want to make this work with proper rss or atom feeds, you may notice that the `feed` contains an XML Namespace (`xmlns`) attribute, just like in this example from YouTube:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<feed xmlns:yt="http://www.youtube.com/xml/schemas/2015" xmlns:media="http://search.yahoo.com/mrss/" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom">
   ...
</feed>
```

Then, above script will no longer work! It caused me quite some headache to fix it, but here is how to make it work:

```
xml ed -d '//_:entry[not(contains(_:title,"Project Foo"))]' < youtube_rss.xml
```

More on this namespace problem here: http://xmlstar.sourceforge.net/doc/UG/ch05.html